# Обработка События по клику в ReactJS из выборки

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Задача, вроде бы, простая, но я нигде но могу найти на неё ответ.
Мне нужно написать менюшку. При нажатии на элемент, остальные похожие элементы сбрасывали стиль, а тот на который я нажал этот стиль рисовал. Как мне это реализовать на reactJS?
В js или jq это не сложно, но как это сделать в reactJS правильно и без кастылей?

Вот мой код

```js
function Menu(){
    const [click, setClick] = useState(false);
    const handleClick = (e: any) => {
        console.log(e.target);
        return setClick(true);
    }

    return (
        <nav className = 'menuNav'>
            <ul>
                <Li click = {click} onClick = {handleClick}>Главная</Li>
                <Li click = {click} onClick = {handleClick}>Обо мне</Li>
                <Li click = {click} onClick = {handleClick}>Скилы</Li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    )
}

function Li(props: any){
    const [mouse, setMouse] = useState(false);
    const handlemouseover = () => setMouse(true);
    const handlemouseout = () => setMouse(false);

    const style = {
        color: mouse ? 'black' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
        borderBottom: props.click ? '1px solid blue' : '1px solid white'
    }

    return (
        <li 
        className = 'menuNav' 
        onMouseEnter = {handlemouseover} 
        onMouseLeave= {handlemouseout} 
        onClick = {props.onClick}
        style = {style}
        >{props.children}</li>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать динамические инлайн стили или класси - это ваш вибор. Для этого массив не нужен, т.к. "помеченый" всегда один. Как вариант:

https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-wildflower-znnw52?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Спасибо огромное, я разобрался в вопросе!!

Answer (score 0):

на элемент надо не стиль вешать, а класс со стилем как состояние

class="{nameClassState}"

```
    const handlemouseover = () => setClass('nameClass');
    const handlemouseout = () => setClass('');
```

Comment: Ну так если я произведу это в ```Menu``` то у меня класс добавиться ко всем li и тогда смысл? И плюс, с событиями handlemouseover и handlemouseout у меня всё в порядке, они отрабатывают как мне нужно. А вот handleClick в компоненте Menu, у меня проблема с тем, что он стили добавляет не на выбранный элемент, а на все

Comment: установить состояние как массив для каждого элемента меню как вариант
className = 'menuNav {classOnclick[props.indexLi]}'
в обработчике переустанавливать состояние с дефолтного